# Why CLGeoCoder cannot get anything?

Tags: swift, location, clgeocoder

I have program a class that can reverse the location into the Geo-information like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
public class Geocoder{
    public static func Geocoder(latitudein:Double,longitudein:Double)->String
    {
        var address:String?="";
        var geocoder = CLGeocoder.init();
        var location:CLLocation=CLLocation.init(latitude: latitudein, longitude: longitudein);

       // var placemarks:[CLPlacemark]=[CLPlacemark].init();
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            for p in placemarks!
            {
                if(p != nil)
                {
                    //print(p);
                   // address?.append(p.country!);
                   // address?.append(p.subAdministrativeArea!);
                    address=p.name;
                }
            }

        }
        print(address);
        return address!;
    }
}
```

but the address is `nil`,I have tried `p.country` and many other parameter,but still return `nil`,I want to ask why and how to solve it?

Comment: You are missing a concept: Asynchrone. `reverseGeocodeLocation()` is async. If you put logs, you'll see that `print(address);` is called BEFORE `address=p.name;`. Look for "Swift + Async + Closure".

Comment: How I can solve it,I am new in swift programming

Comment: Don't use `;` as line terminators in Swift, and don't start func names with uppercase letters

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public static func Geocoder(latitudein:Double,longitudein:Double,completion:@escaping(_ address:String?) -> Void )
{

    var geocoder = CLGeocoder.init();
    var location:CLLocation=CLLocation.init(latitude: latitudein, longitude: longitudein);

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in


       if error != nil {
           completion(nil)
           return
        } 

        for p in placemarks!
        {
            if(p != nil)
            {
                completion(p.name)
                break
            }
        }

    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    VCName.Geocoder(latitudein: 20.555, longitudein: 30.777) { (address) in
        if let ad = address {


        }
    }

}
```